# PostgreSQL 9.6 casting trouble

Tags: postgresql, casting

I have the next function : `func1(a text, b text, c text)`. I summon it with arguments that aren't text - func1( d,e,f) when d is a numeric type, b is bigint type and c is timezone type. I found a comment that suggested to create automatic casting and I did so :

```
CREATE CAST (int AS text) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
CREATE CAST (bigint AS text) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
CREATE CAST (numeric AS text) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
CREATE CAST (timezone AS text) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```

Now suddenly, I got error in other function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Bl_Create_Flat_File_Pg.open_table (file_id utl_file.file_type,temp_variable text, p_percent_width bigint DEFAULT 100, p_border bigint DEFAULT 1) RETURNS VOID AS $body$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'INSIDE OPEN_TABLE FUNC';
**PERFORM utl_file.put_line(file_id, '<TABLE BORDER='||p_border||'  
WIDTH='||p_percent_width||'%>');**
End;
```

The error I get is `operator is not unique: unknown || bigint`. So I decided to delete the casts that I created and it solved the problem but it took me to the first stage again - trying to summon the function without manual casting.

What can I try next?

Comment: You could create overloaded versions of your function with the different data types, and call the actual function by casting the input.

Comment: Yes I can but this solution is much easier instead of createing overloaded version of my func. Im not sure how many version of argument I'm sending (Im migration an oracle app and I didnt finsh yet..). Do you understand why I'm having this problem?